# В разных серверах postgresql копируются данные

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Вопрос очень глупый, но помогите, пожалуйста.

В постгрес по дефолту есть группа серверов Servers, где указан сервер постгреса PostgreSQL 14, там и в целом производится работа. Но я хочу создать ещё одну группу серверов, я её создаю, создаю там сервер с адресом 127.0.0.1 и туда перегоняются все базы данных. То есть получается просто копирка основного сервера постгреса, но я хочу чтобы они были разные естественно.

Почему так и что мне с этим сделать, чтобы мой сервер не копировал всё то же самое? Дело в том что это всё локалхост или что?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дело в том, что перед вами средство доступа к уже существующим серверам postgresql. И вы не создаете в нем сервера, а просто описываете как подключиться к уже существующему серверу.  Надо отдельно устанавливать сервер, настраивать его на работу на другом адресе (или другом порту) и делается это не с помощью этого средства, а руками, в том числе с правкой различных конфигурационных файлов. Для начала можно попробовать воспользоваться инталлятором postgresql, только надо постараться случайно не затереть существующую БД

Comment: Правда еще остается вопрос, а зачем вообще потребовались отдельные сервера на одной машине.